# Is there a recommended strategy for releasing a beta version of an application to a limited number of users through the Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play, release

I would like to distribute a beta version of my application to a small group of users.  Ideally this would be done through the market to make it easier for the beta testers.

Is there a way to restrict an app's presence in the market?  The only solutions I could come up with were:

1 - Have users download the .adk from the web and install manually
2 - Release the beta version as a separate app in the market

The first option isn't ideal as you have to potentially walk the user through allowing apps from unknown sources.  Not to mention from a user perspective, you're then downloading an app from an untrusted source.

The second option isn't ideal as you then are potentially confusing other users by having multiple versions in the market, one of which might be flaky.  And then there's the inevitable comments about how something doesn't work in the market.  I guess you could add some sort of password to that version that you only distribute to your beta testers.

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Market is for public apps only so there is not any good ways to do this. Our app was distributed by email as apk when we where doing beta-testing. Use android forums to get beta-testers.

But, if you insist on using android market. I suggest re-name your app and package-names, and put it into the demo category. But again, I would not used android market for beta-testing.

Comment: Actually, the demo category is meant for fully working and stable demo-versions of retail apps. So, it might not be a good idea afterall. Try sending a email to google for an answer how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps put a relatively high price on it and refund the beta users' money.

Comment: Ideally the solution wouldn't require signing up for Google Checkout either I guess.  My application is free, so I don't have an account.  I haven't checked, but doesn't Google still take a cut when you issue a refund like that?

And I'm sure user's might not be too happy about having to trust that you'll refund the "relatively high price."

Comment: Looks like you would be able to refund the fee without being charged according to this: http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138001

Still looking for a more user friendly way.  And technically this wouldn't restrict anyone who didn't mind paying a high fee.

Comment: Also, Google Checkout is not available in many countries... e.g Norway ;-)